# MYSQL Weighing Results

Tags: mysql, frequency

What is the typical way to weigh results in MYSQL?

I have a table with a column called 'category_id' which goes from 1-10.

How do I weigh results so a higher frequency of results with one category_id will show up vs. another?

Comment: If you have already thought of `GROUP BY` then I didn't understand your question at all.

Comment: You mean `ORDER BY`  clause ?

Comment: @safarov No I meant GROUP BY. The user wants results regarding the frequency of occurrences.

Comment: I mean I want to return 100 results, but 50% of them should be category_id 1, 25% should be category_id and rest category_id 3-10 depending on what percentages I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select category_id, count(*) 
from table 
group by category_id order by count(*) desc
```

assuming you are using a table named `table`

To get the weights like you were saying, you can use two queries:

```
set @a := (select count(*) from table);

select category_id, count(*)/@a from table group by category_id order by count(*) desc;
```

maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
(select * from table where category_id = 1 order by rand() limit 50)
union all
(select * from table where category_id = 2 order by rand() limit 25)
union all
(select * from table where category_id = 3 order by rand() limit 25)
```

this will give you 100 rows, split up 50/25/25 by category ids 1,2,3.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I was actually not referring to finding the frequency. I was trying to figure out a way to write a query that would generate a certain frequency.

Comment: Jeff - this gives you the weights from the results.

Comment: Is there a way to write it such that 25% of results will always have category_id=1?

Comment: The last part I wrote there is not so robust I abmit, maybe gives you something to work with.  Do you mean you want to RANDOMLY return results with 25% from category 1, 30% from category 2 ...

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Looks like may need to do 3 unions.

Comment: OK you can use the `order by rand()` clause to get random data, see answer.

Comment: @user1124535 - check my update with the `union all` syntax combines your results into to result set.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to favor, say, category `5`, you  can do something in the lines of:

```
select id, description
from your table
where yourcondition='conditionvalue'
order by 
    case category
       when 5 then 0
       else 1
    end, 
    category
```